# How we transform IS inputs to VC (reduction)?

Tags: complexity-theory, np-hard, np

I would like to clarify something in my understanding of proving a problem to be NP-hard.
So in short, what I know is that:
"If I have a problem A that I want to prove that is NP-hard and another well -known NP-hard problem B and I can find a polynomial time reduction R such that if I answer A I know the answer to B as well for all the possible inputs to problem B , then I have proved that $B \leq_P A$ which means that "A is harder or as hard as B which is known to be hard already" and therefore A is NP-hard."
What confuses me is that I see sometimes some proofs that show that two algorithmic questions (or at least that's what I think that they are proving) **are completely equivalent but not by transforming the inputs of one to another but by simply providing an argument that states that they are equivalent**.
What do I mean :
Let's say we know Independent Set (IS) is NP-hard and we want to show that vertex cover (VC) is  NP-hard. If I understand well the well-known method is to claim this :
Let's say we want to find out whether an IS of at least k vectices exists in $G(V,E)$.
Now we take **this very same G (no transformation perfomed on it)** and ask the question : "Is there a vertex cover S of at most n-k vertices"?
If I find one and then delete the vertices of it the $|V|-|S|$ vertices that are left form an independent set. That's true because let's say they do not : then there is at least an edge $(u,v)$ such that $u,v \in V-S$ so it was "never really covered by our VC ".
But $|S|$ has at most n-k vertices and therefore the $V-S$ has at least $k$ vertices.
So what is the transformation here ? In the part we delete the vertices of $S$ we create an induced subgraph of G which is a transformation but I am not sure how it connects to "the whole method of proving this as NP-hard" .
(I hope my question makes sense I tried hard to put it into words)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can express this idea as a reduction.

IS consists of all pairs $\langle G,k \rangle$, where $G$ is a graph which contains an independent set of size at least $k$.

VC consists of all pairs $\langle G,k \rangle$, where $G$ is a graph which contains a vertex cover of size at most $k$.

To reduce IS to VC, take an instance $\langle G,k \rangle$ of IS to the instance $\langle G,n-k \rangle$ of VC, where $n$ is the number of vertices in $G$.

In this case there is also a reduction between the problem of finding a maximum independent set in a graph and the problem of finding a minimum vertex cover in a graph. Given a graph $G = (V,E)$, find a minimum vertex cover $S$, and output the independent set $V \setminus S$. This is a different type of reduction, and the problems are also of a different kind.

Comment: thank you for your answer . So have I understood well that in this reduction : we do not really change the input of IS but rather we do change the question we are asking on it ? (we search for an IS of size at least k or we search for a VC  that's at most n-k?)?

Comment: An instance of IS is a pair $\langle G,k \rangle$. Both parts of the pair are part of the instance.

Comment: thank you I did not think about that to be honest